# Where is the link from this meta back to the main CiviCRM StackExchange?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

just wondering...

I cant find my way back :-(

there should be a link somewhere but I cant finde it... am I blind?

(And now apparently I have to write an essay to get past the question quality control robot.)

Answer (score 1):

mmm... I found it... the link is under "stack exchange"

still seems weird to have links all over the page but to have the main one hidden in a menu

Comment: The [top bar redesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420) was [not universally loved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613), but the philosophy behind it is that any change of "environment"— whether from one stack to another, from main to meta, or from QA to chat or blog— should be centrally accessible.

Comment: @choster - maybe some more thought needs to go into the special relationship between a site and its meta!

Comment: There's also a link in the help menu. Normally, you would find the link to the meta site in the top left StackExchange menu, so it's natural to use that same menu to go back. The “got a question about the site itself?” bar only appears during the initial formative period of the site, for a few weeks.

Comment: Its still pretty obscure isn't it? "help" is not the first place your eye goes. I'm sure I wasn't the first person who scanned the roughly 30 - 50 links to other sites featured prominently to right and below...

Comment: @ErichBSchulz I agree. The meta site is more easily accessible from the main site (by the "Hot Meta Posts" frame) than vice versa. On the meta site, there should be a frame saying "Hot Main Posts" that point to the main site.